# In which circumstances should you use listview instead of listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, listview

Like the topic I was wondering of there are any circumstances one should use the regular ListView instead of the ListView.builder in flutter, like if there are few items in a list could the ListView give better performance?

Answer (score 1):

ListView has actually four different ways to use it , But let discuss ListView and ListView.builder

**ListView**  : It has a children
property that takes a collection of static widgets. A ListView takes a small number of other widgets and makes it scrollable. Why a “small number”? Because this is designed to be a static list, one that you, the developer, simply types into the build() method
by hand.

**ListView.builder** : ListView’s alternative constructor, ListView.builder receives two
parameters, an itemCount and an ItemBuilder property that is a
function. This makes the ListView lazy-loaded. The itemBuilder function
dynamically creates children widgets on demand. As the user scrolls close
to the bottom of the list, itemBuilder creates new items to be scrolled into
view. And when we scroll something far enough off the screen, it is paged
out of memory and disposed of. Pretty cool.

Reference : taken from [Rap Payne's Beginning App Development with Flutter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484251806) (Great Book for beginners! , not an affiliate link).

official documentation for [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) .

Comment: @hackergo if you find the answer useful , you should accept it .

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is the most commonly used scrolling widget. It displays its children one after another in the scroll direction. So if you just want to show some widgets below earch other and you need to scroll them you use ListView.

`ListView.builder` is a way of constructing the list where children’s (Widgets) are built on demand. However, instead of returning a static widget, it calls a function which can be called multiple times (based on `itemCount` ) and it’s possible to return different widget at each call.

Comment: But in the case I am using ListView, should I not always use ListView.builder as it would give me better performance?

Comment: @hackergo builder is when you want to dynamically show a list, for example if you want to fetch a list from an api

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple answer you were looking for is:

Use `ListView.builder` whenever you iterate over an array of 'similar' elements.

Use `ListView` when items in your list are completely different from one another.

Think of `ListView` as scrollable Column